# functional equation $f(xf(y)) + f(yf(x)) = 1 + f(x + y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, contest-math, functional-equations

How do we find all smooth functions $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$f(xf(y)) + f(yf(x)) = 1 + f(x + y)$$
for all $x, y > 0$? By comparing degrees, the only polynomial solution is $f(x) = 1$. We can deduce from above that $\inf f \leq 1$, and $\sup f \geq 1$. But can we show that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$? Or is this not the solution.

Comment: This is B6 on this year's Putnam, although the Putnam problem asks for continuous functions. not necessarily smooth functions.

Comment: This is not a good thing from you to **hide** the fact that it is Putnam competition of this year.

Comment: Is it allowed to answer this question?

Comment: @Hypernova It would be better to wait for the asker reacts to the remarks done.

Comment: @JeanMarie The Putnam exam was finished yesterday, so it should be fine to discuss the problems?

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: @JeanMarie I found the solutions here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3218028_2022_putnam